# Does the Bone Dagger still drop in manors?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I've done a lot of manors now, but I haven't gotten a single bone dagger. I thought they were not rare. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Realm Eye](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/bone-dagger) : Yes.

> **Bone Dagger**
>
> ***Drops From:***
>
> Lord Ruthven
>
> Coffin
>
> Nosferatu